# How do I keep the padding in a contenteditable div the same way it is kept in a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, padding, contenteditable

When I set the `padding` in a `textarea` with `overflow:scroll`, it keeps that `padding`, even when the scrollbar is displayed. The same does not happen with a `contenteditable` div, as shown in the following example, where both the div and the textarea have the same style applied:

https://jsfiddle.net/xa7b4f8y/

```css
.contentEditable, .textArea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>contenteditable:</h3>
<div class="contentEditable" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></div>
<h3>textarea:</h3>
<textarea class="textArea" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

As you can see, in the contenteditable div, only the `padding-left` is kept, whereas in the textarea, it keeps the 20px padding on all four sides.

[image]

How can I have padding in the contenteditable behave the same way it does in a textarea?

I am running this on Firefox 78. On Chrome 84, both work the same way - only left and right padding is kept, which is also not the desired outcome.

Comment: what browser? for me both behave the same when using chrome

Comment: I am using Firefox 78. I will update the question, to add that information.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best solution but you can hack it using pseudo element that you make sticky on the padding area with a white background.

```css
.contentEditable,
.textArea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding:20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contentEditable::before,
.contentEditable::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  position:sticky;
  background:#fff;
} 
.contentEditable::before {
  margin-top:-19px;
  top:-19px;
}
.contentEditable::after {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
  bottom:-20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>contenteditable:</h3>
<div class="contentEditable" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></div>
<h3>textarea:</h3>
<textarea class="textArea" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```